# General questions on .NET Entity Framework 4

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-4, asp.net-mvc-4

I've got a few questions in regards to the EF 4.0 which I hope someone can help me with.

A little bit of background first: I used a tool from visualstudiogallery.com to reverse engineer my database into classes. All appears to be fine in regards to the classes, object mapping, etc... In my dbcontext class, it generated a property for each table which is fine. Now this part of the code is held in one project and it's being called by an MVC 4 application. I'll eventually turn this into a full service layer to deal with separation of concern but for now a direct link will do the trick.

Anyway, back to my EF questions:

1. I'm confused as to what EF does here when accessing a propery in the dbcontext class which matches the table name? Does it actually return all the rows every time? Seems insane if it does
2. I tried creating a function rather than a property in the dbcontext class where I wanted to provide a parameter and return only rows matching the parameter but when I add a class and try to make a "LINQ" call within it, I get the following error:

Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet .... 'Select' not found.  Are you missing a reference to 'System.Core.dll' or a using directive for 'System.Linq'?

Any ideas why this is happening?

1. I assume this is more a link question, but assume we have a users table (userid), a horse table (horseid) and then one table where horses are associated to users (horseid, userid).

If I created a function, assuming 2 is resolved, which is called GetMyHorses and I pass the userId as a parameter, how do I use Linq to provide what I would normally get via a simple join query in stored procedure and return all horses associated with the user provided via the parameter.

Thanks.

Comment: Lot's of questions in one. I suggest you seperate them into individual questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both your questions are related to the LINQ pipeline, the `IQueryable` interface and delayed execution. You'll need to study these above-mentioned topics.

But to answer your questions:

1. No, Entity Framework does not load all (for e.g.) `Horses` when you say

   var ctx = YourHorsesContext();

   ```
       // At this time, it simply builds a query that it will fire later.
       var horses = ctx.Horses;

       foreach(Horse horse in horses) // it fires a SQL query here
           Console.WriteLine(horse);  // if you don't foreach, it will never fire a SQL query
   ```
2. Type this:

   using System.Linq;

at the top of your class file. Your code should work.